# ANN algorithm for system selection

Tags: neural-network, rnn, lstm

I have a dataset of computer systems with system characteristics as parameters. I want to rank best systems based on these parameters. The system works on a recurrent neural network model with the inputs of all previous transactions considered while choosing the current output. To my understanding, LSTM is something that is commonly used for such usecases but I heard it has limitations when I want to dynamically add new systems.  Are there any better alternatives?

Comment: Can you provide more details? What is the notion of "best system" here? Do you have a labeled dataset with system scores or ranks? "The system works...": is this the same system as "dataset of computer systems"? The terminology is confusing.

Comment: Yes , I meant a set of computer systems with machine characteristics . So i would like to get rank say the 5 best , high performance systems based upon these features .  The network depends also on the previous output of the system , So something like a RNN.